# 6-Core Xeon VS Opteron for virtualization

Tags: virtualization, xeon, opteron

Which processor gives better price/performance for virtualization environment?

Comment: **We need more details to give a good answer**. What hypervisor are you using? What kind of workload? If you have a pricing deal with one reseller or manufacturer that will effect the price...

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend dual Nehalem Xeons (w/ 8MB L3 cache, [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon#Nehalem_based_Xeon)) as the optimum price/performance chips for VMWare ESXi virtualization right now - they're old enough to be cheap but still powerful enough to run lots of big VMs. Generally you won't run into performance problems with CPUs though, you'd be better off spending the cash you save on 32+ GBs of RAM.

(caveat: this is obviously subjective and dependant on application)

Comment: I'm upvoting this one for the part that says you'd be better off worrying about more RAM.

Comment: +1 for comment on more RAM

Answer (score 4):

This can't be answered as prices are relative based on who's buying.

It also depends on whether your hypervisor of choice can deal with hyperthreading well.

Comment: Also depends on the workload of the VMs. Some programs run faster on each of the given processors.